# having an issue with an if then statement using vbYesNo

Tags: if-statement, printing, vbscript

I am trying to create a script that will ask the user if they want to set a network printer as their default. My problem is that no matter what they select (yes or no) it set it up as the default and it always echo's my the echo statement under else. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

`    ' Printers.vbs - Windows Logon Script.

```
   printername = "DCPTTEAM462W"
   server = "DCDEPLOY03"

   Dim objectNetwork, printer
   printer = "\\DCPRINT03\DCPTTEAM462W"

   Msgbox printername & " will now install on your computer.",0, "Add printer" & printername  


   intRespnseY = Msgbox("Would you like " & printername & " to be set as your default printer", vbYesNo, "Set as Default")


   If intResponseY = vbNo Then

   Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
   objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection printer
   WScript.Echo "DCPTTEAM462W was added as a printer."

   Else

   Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
   objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection printer
   objNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter printer
   WScript.Echo "DCPTTEAM462W has been set as your default printer."

   End If
```

`

Comment: Great thanks that fixed the echo issue however it is still setting the printer as a default.

Comment: Thanks for you help guys. I saw that my issue was that after I removed the printer it was setting Workshare PDF Publisher as my default printer. If I changed my default printer to another printer and ran the script it worked as designed. The culprit was the 'o' as mentioned below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
intRespnseY = Msgbox(....
```

Should be

```
intResponseY = Msgbox(....
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Option Explicit
```

to avoid blunders like:

```
intRespnseY = Msgbox("...")
If intResponseY = vbNo Then
```

(mark the missing "o")